# Liferay - Select item filled with json responseData

Tags: javascript, java, arraylist, liferay-6, liferay-aui

It's my first post on stackoverflow so I hope I won't make too many mistakes.

I've a problem with filling Java List and sending it to aui:select as options. My goal is to fill **aui:select** dynamically whenever one of their options is changed. For example: if you change first select item (county), second and third items (community and city respectively) are emptied and then filled with data dependent on selected county.

I've come to a conclusion that whenever there's a **"mvcPath"** parameter in Query String Parameters this code basically copies code from the whole page. This code works well whenever there's no **"mvcPath"** though. Sadly, I need this parameter to change pages (from search results to selected result details).

[Image showing badly filled select item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1Cu7.png)

[Image showing correctly filled select item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gR46D.png)

Java code:

```
    @Override
public void serveResource(ResourceRequest resourceRequest, ResourceResponse resourceResponse)
        throws IOException, PortletException {
    String communityName = "";
    long communityId = 0;
    String cityName = "";
    long cityId = 0;
    String countySelected = ParamUtil.getString(resourceRequest, "countySelected");
    long countySelectedId = ParamUtil.getLong(resourceRequest, "countyDictionaryId");
    String communitySelected = ParamUtil.getString(resourceRequest, "communitySelected");
    long communitySelectedId = ParamUtil.getLong(resourceRequest, "communityDictionaryId");
    JSONArray jsonArray = JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONArray();
    if (countySelected.equalsIgnoreCase("countySelected") && countySelectedId != 0) {
        System.out.println("County id: " + countySelectedId);
        try {
            int communitiesCount = CommunityDictionaryLocalServiceUtil.getCommunityDictionariesCount();
            List<CommunityDictionary> communities = CommunityDictionaryLocalServiceUtil.getCommunityDictionaries(0,
                    communitiesCount);
            for (CommunityDictionary community : communities) {
                if (community.getCountyDictionaryId() == countySelectedId) {
                    communityName = community.getCommunityName();
                    communityId = community.getCommunityDictionaryId();
                    JSONObject communityObject = JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONObject();
                    communityObject.put("communityName", communityName);
                    communityObject.put("communityDictionaryId", communityId);
                    jsonArray.put(communityObject);
                    System.out.print(jsonArray.toString());
                }
            }
        } catch (SystemException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else if (countySelected.equalsIgnoreCase("countySelected") && countySelectedId == 0) {
        System.out.println("No county chosen.");
        try {
            int communitiesCount = CommunityDictionaryLocalServiceUtil.getCommunityDictionariesCount();
            List<CommunityDictionary> communities = CommunityDictionaryLocalServiceUtil.getCommunityDictionaries(0,
                    communitiesCount);
            for (CommunityDictionary community : communities) {
                communityName = community.getCommunityName();
                communityId = community.getCommunityDictionaryId();
                JSONObject communityObject = JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONObject();
                communityObject.put("communityName", communityName);
                communityObject.put("communityDictionaryId", communityId);
                jsonArray.put(communityObject);
            }
        } catch (SystemException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if (communitySelected.equalsIgnoreCase("communitySelected") && communitySelectedId != 0) {
        System.out.println("Community id: " + communitySelectedId);
        try {
            int citiesCount = CityDictionaryLocalServiceUtil.getCityDictionariesCount();
            List<CityDictionary> cities = CityDictionaryLocalServiceUtil.getCityDictionaries(0, citiesCount);
            for (CityDictionary city : cities) {
                if (city.getCommunityDictionaryId() == communitySelectedId) {
                    cityName = city.getCityName();
                    cityId = city.getCityDictionaryId();
                    JSONObject cityObject = JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONObject();
                    cityObject.put("cityName", cityName);
                    cityObject.put("cityDictionaryId", cityId);
                    jsonArray.put(cityObject);
                    System.out.print(jsonArray.toString());
                }
            }
        } catch (SystemException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else if (communitySelected.equalsIgnoreCase("communitySelected") && communitySelectedId == 0) {
        System.out.println("No community chosen.");
        try {
            int citiesCount = CityDictionaryLocalServiceUtil.getCityDictionariesCount();
            List<CityDictionary> cities = CityDictionaryLocalServiceUtil.getCityDictionaries(0, citiesCount);
            for (CityDictionary city : cities) {
                cityName = city.getCityName();
                cityId = city.getCityDictionaryId();
                JSONObject cityObject = JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONObject();
                cityObject.put("cityName", cityName);
                cityObject.put("cityDictionaryId", cityId);
                jsonArray.put(cityObject);
            }
        } catch (SystemException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    PrintWriter writer = resourceResponse.getWriter();
    writer.write(jsonArray.toString());
    writer.flush();
    super.serveResource(resourceRequest, resourceResponse);
}
```

Script:

```
<aui:script>
AUI().use('aui-base', 'aui-io-request', 'aui-node',
        function(A) {A.one("#<portlet:namespace />countySelect").on('change', function() {
            A.io.request('<%= selectionChangedURL %>',
                    {
                method : 'POST',
                data : {
                    "<portlet:namespace />countyDictionaryId" : A.one("#<portlet:namespace />countySelect").val(),
                    '<portlet:namespace />countySelected' : 'countySelected'
                    },
                    dataType : 'json',
                    on : {
                        success : function() {
                            var communitiesList = this.get('responseData');
                            A.one('#<portlet:namespace />communitySelect').empty();
                            A.one('#<portlet:namespace />citySelect').empty();
                            A.one('#<portlet:namespace />communitySelect').prepend("<option value='0'> </option>");
                            for (var i in communitiesList) {
                                console.info(communitiesList[i]);
                                A.one('#<portlet:namespace />communitySelect').append("<option value='" + communitiesList[i].communityDictionaryId + "'>" + communitiesList[i].communityName + "</option>");
                                }
                            }
                    }
                    });
            });
        A.one("#<portlet:namespace />communitySelect").on('change', function() {
            A.io.request('<%= selectionChangedURL %>',
                    {
                method : 'POST',
                data : {
                    "<portlet:namespace />communityDictionaryId" : A.one("#<portlet:namespace />communitySelect").val(),
                    '<portlet:namespace />communitySelected' : 'communitySelected'
                    },
                    dataType : 'json',
                    on : {
                        success : function() {
                            var citiesList = this.get('responseData');
                            A.one('#<portlet:namespace />citySelect').empty();
                            A.one('#<portlet:namespace />citySelect').prepend("<option value='0'> </option>");
                            for (var i in citiesList) {
                                console.info(citiesList[i]);
                                A.one('#<portlet:namespace />citySelect').append("<option value='" + citiesList[i].cityDictionaryId + "'>" + citiesList[i].cityName + "</option>");
                                }
                            }
                    }
                    });
            });
        });
```

Comment: for loop in javascript code looks confusing to me, i seems one element of array and it seems used as counter...  Are you getting proper information printed in browser console?

Comment: Thanks for a response! In the second attached picture You can see correctly printed information. It's working as intended as long as I don't use mvcPath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some changes in server-side code I managed to fix this issue. I'm not really sure how did as small changes as those helped but I'm happy to close this thread.

This is the server-side code:

```
public void serveResource(ResourceRequest resourceRequest, ResourceResponse resourceResponse)
        throws IOException, PortletException {
    String communityName = "";
    long communityId = 0;
    String cityName = "";
    long cityId = 0;
    String countySelected = ParamUtil.getString(resourceRequest, "countySelected");
    long countySelectedId = ParamUtil.getLong(resourceRequest, "countyDictionaryId");
    String communitySelected = ParamUtil.getString(resourceRequest, "communitySelected");
    long communitySelectedId = ParamUtil.getLong(resourceRequest, "communityDictionaryId");
    JSONArray jsonArray = JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONArray();
    if (countySelected.equalsIgnoreCase("countySelected")) {
        try {
            int communitiesCount = CommunityDictionaryLocalServiceUtil.getCommunityDictionariesCount();
            List<CommunityDictionary> communities = CommunityDictionaryLocalServiceUtil.getCommunityDictionaries(0,
                    communitiesCount);
            if (countySelectedId == 0) {
                for (CommunityDictionary community : communities) {
                    communityName = community.getCommunityName();
                    communityId = community.getCommunityDictionaryId();
                    JSONObject communityObject = JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONObject();
                    communityObject.put("communityName", communityName);
                    communityObject.put("communityDictionaryId", communityId);
                    jsonArray.put(communityObject);
                }
            } else {
                for (CommunityDictionary community : communities) {
                    if (community.getCountyDictionaryId() == countySelectedId) {
                        communityName = community.getCommunityName();
                        communityId = community.getCommunityDictionaryId();
                        JSONObject communityObject = JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONObject();
                        communityObject.put("communityName", communityName);
                        communityObject.put("communityDictionaryId", communityId);
                        jsonArray.put(communityObject);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (SystemException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if (communitySelected.equalsIgnoreCase("communitySelected")) {
        try {
            int citiesCount = CityDictionaryLocalServiceUtil.getCityDictionariesCount();
            List<CityDictionary> cities = CityDictionaryLocalServiceUtil.getCityDictionaries(0, citiesCount);
            if (communitySelectedId == 0) {
                for (CityDictionary city : cities) {
                    cityName = city.getCityName();
                    cityId = city.getCityDictionaryId();
                    JSONObject cityObject = JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONObject();
                    cityObject.put("cityName", cityName);
                    cityObject.put("cityDictionaryId", cityId);
                    jsonArray.put(cityObject);
                }
            } else {
                for (CityDictionary city : cities) {
                    if (city.getCommunityDictionaryId() == communitySelectedId) {
                        cityName = city.getCityName();
                        cityId = city.getCityDictionaryId();
                        JSONObject cityObject = JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONObject();
                        cityObject.put("cityName", cityName);
                        cityObject.put("cityDictionaryId", cityId);
                        jsonArray.put(cityObject);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (SystemException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(resourceResponse.getPortletOutputStream());
    writer.write(jsonArray.toString());
    writer.flush();
    super.serveResource(resourceRequest, resourceResponse);
}
```